# Handling CONNECT request with Nginx Ingress on GCP GKE

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress

I have a cluster of proxy servers on GKE, and I'm trying to figure out how to load balance CONNECT requests to these.

Without GKE, I'm using the nginx stream module (http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html) which works perfectly.

GCP load balancers do not accept CONNECT requests, so I'm trying to take my existing nginx configuration file and apply it to an nginx ingress resource for GKE. Is this possible?

Comment: You can always setup your own nginx ingress controller as a LB and apply existing configuration for it.  Also, where the statement `GCP load balancers do not accept CONNECT requests` comes from?

Comment: The out of the box load balancer rejects requests with "Cannot handle method request type CONNECT, that's all we know"

Comment: @aproscott Did you manage to apply existing config for nginx ingress controller?

Comment: @A_Suh I did not, and I don't understand why this is so hard. I just want to use my existing nginx.conf file (which works) and apply it to kubernetes

Comment: can you elaborate what is the issue?  you can not copy config file or it doesn't work?  to copy file `kubectl cp /etc/nginx/nginx.conf <ingress-controller-pod>:etc/nginx/` to apply new config `kk exec -it <ingress-controller-pod> -- nginx -s reload`

Comment: Not yet, i'm trying to follow this https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/custom-nginx but might come back to trying what you're suggesting